# website not working on IOS and MAC but works on Windows and Android

Tags: ios, reactjs, macos, react-redux, safari

I have been building an [E-commerce site](https://fascinating-heliotrope-79c0ec.netlify.app) for the last month and deployed it to [netlify](https://www.netlify.com).

But the problem is that my site only shows a blank page on ios and Mac devices but works on Windows and Android devices.

On machines where the site does not load properly, there is no error but when I inspect my site, it shows my root div in the body tag is empty and I have no idea what is wrong.

Browsers that does not load my site correctly:

- chrome on an iphone12 pro max version 103.0.5060.63
- safari on iphone12 pro max version 15.5
- safari on mac version 15.1

**GitHub repository:** https://github.com/falconcode95/bogaad-store

**Live site link:** https://fascinating-heliotrope-79c0ec.netlify.app

Comment: For the sake of inspection, I can verify that the [linked site](https://fascinating-heliotrope-79c0ec.netlify.app/)  **does work** correctly on my system. (Firefox 102.0.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

Comment: Since interpretation of websites, for the most part, is controlled by browsers rather than operating systems, it is recommended to provide the concerned browser names and versions.

Comment: It also works on my windows laptop and android tablet but it does not work on a mac or an iphone

Comment: Go on to [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) and try to open your website on Safari browser in a Mac device. They allow upto 1 minute of testing per device for free without the need for credit card.

Comment: I also tested it on Chrome version 103.0.5060.114 on Ubuntu 22.04LTS, and still works fine. The issue might be with firewall?

Comment: i have tried BrowserStack but it says connection to the remote device failed constantly while i have internet and everything is working :(

Comment: Opening the site on Safari and checking the Javascript console reveals the following error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name` - It seems that Safari cannot execute the javascript required to render your site.

Comment: i see it let me see if i can find a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason my site was not working on IOS and MAC devices was because i was using a lookbehind regex pattern (?<=a)b and from what i researched so far they don't support those so i just wrote a function that manually checks for that specific pattern instead and now my site works on all platforms!

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem! But whenever you answer your own question, you need to accept it, so other people know it is solved :)